# Letter 'ć' doesn't work in chrome ('ą', 'ę', etc. work)

Tags: google-chrome, special-characters

On a Mac, Monterey, in Chrome whenever I press Option + c I expect 'ć' to appear. It never does. That's a special chars in the Polish language. Other special chars appear (ą, ę, ł, ó, ż, ź, ś, ń), that one doesn't. In all other programs (that I tried) it works perfectly fine, including safari.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/5150864)? Is it helpful?

Comment: Yes, this was copy all urls extension :( Thank you!

Comment: I don't use Mac, I don't use Chrome, I don't like writing about things I cannot test, so I won't write an answer. [You are now the best person to answer your question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer).